# I have two grub.cfg files

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to dual-boot Windows 10 and Kubuntu but since I tried setting grub as my boot manager with `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` in Windows' BCDEdit, my screen is Black until I log in to Windows (no BIOS POST or Grub menu). I just found out that I have to grub.cfg files. One in /boot/grub/grub.cfg on my / Partition and one on an unnamed FAT32 boot partition under [\EFI\ubuntu\grub.cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x46TY.png). I don't know which on is read when booting, I don't know if I should delete. Also if I'd run update-grub would only one file update? Maybe the one I don't need?

If you know what's going on here, please help me because I don't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also I just noticed it changes my bootmanager to SHIMX6.EFI every time I reboot.

Comment: Shimx64.efi is for UEFI boot, but also works if Secure Boot is off. Ubuntu has a tiny 3 line grub.cfg in ESP that using configfile to load the full grub.cfg in your install. You need both. Better to use grub to dual boot. example UEFI configfile:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205982/how-make-external-usb-disk-bootable-for-bios-and-uefi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **not** delete any of this two files. In recent versions of grub-efi both files are needed.

`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` is created during bootloader-installation and will be overwritten with `grub-install`. The file contains only a few lines which tell grub where to find further configuration files.

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is this further configuration file. It contains detailed configuration about grub's behaviour (menu, timeout, etc) and the menuentries (including submenus). This is the file which will be updated (overwritten) by `update-grub`.

`shimx64.efi` is needed when you have secure boot enabled in your firmware settings, you may try to disable secure boot and see if things work as expected then.