# Grub not finding my Fedora on other hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm running a triple boot Windows/Ubuntu/Fedora (I just installed Fedora) and unfortunately my grub doesn't find Fedora. I tried a few solutions online (update the grub, os-prober...) but nothing has worked.

On my understanding I have to add an entry to the file 40_custom, but I'm not sure what to enter exactly. The location of my Fedora is `/dev/dm-0`, UUID `8d366751-d6fb-4ada-a807-c090ae6ba61e`.

The Fedora is on vfat and it's the latest (36), Ubuntu is 22.04

Could anyone help me?

thanks!

Comment: You haven't provided any release details; nor what *file-systems* are involved; as some *fs* (eg. `btrfs`) are harder to handle and thus can be skipped in `update-grub`.

Comment: oh sorry! So the Fedora is on `vfat` and it's the latest (36), Ubuntu is 22.04.

Comment: You may need drivers in Ubuntu as Fedora is using different configuration. And full  install cannot be in vfat, but that may be UEFI boot files? Best to see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred here is the report: https://pastebin.com/KxMaHSmZ 

thank you!

Comment: Do you have btrfs drivers in Ubuntu & then mount Fedora partition before running os-prober? Of use a grub configfile in 40_custom to load the Fedora ESP entry,/efi/fedora/grub.cfg,  from the Ubuntu grub, so Fedora  boots directly from its ESP entry. Similar to this but with your ESP's UUID (or label) and /efi/fedora/grub.cfg as grub to load.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205982/how-make-external-usb-disk-bootable-for-bios-and-uefi or https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359

Comment: thanks @oldfred !

- I have installed the btrfs drivers and made sure the Fedora partition was mounted but it didn't change the os-probe result
- I have edited the 40_custom like this:

`menuentry "Fedora" {
    set root=(hd1,1)
     linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/dm-0 ro quiet splash
    initrd /efi/fedora/grub.cfg
}
`
So now I have the Fedora entry in the Grub, but it says it cannot find /boot/vmlinuz and I need to load the kernel first. I'm guessing I just need to change that path to something else?

Comment: If using a boot stanza, it is past the grub.cfg in /efi/fedora, but using grub in your install. You probably can just copy Fedora's boot stanza into Ubuntu's 40_custom. That would give you the correct entry. Only a three line (or even one line) configfile entry is required to load the /efi/fedora/grub.cfg. Not sure how grub sees nvme drives, or which is nvme1n1p1 for ESP. Could just `configfile (hd1,1)/efi/fedora/grub.cfg` Go to grub command line when booting at grub menu & do `ls` & then `ls /efi` to see which drive & partition is correct.