# Fix Grub2 boot with encrypted root LUKS partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, encryption

I currently have 3 different boot partitions:

1. Windows 11 on **nvme0n1**
2. Fedora 35 on **nvme1n1**
3. Ubuntu 22.04 on **sdc** with an encrypted root partition on **sdc4**

When I initially configure the system the **Windows** partition and the **Ubuntu** partition dual boot on the the same **/boot** (**nvme0n1p1**). Due to a system error I had to reinstall Windows which made my Ubuntu partition unbootable, using the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) I was able recreate the menu entry on the grub entry in the **Fedora** partition.

I'm able to boot into Ubuntu from the Fedora boot partition (same from on Ubuntu boot partition) but I'm always prompt with **initramfs** where I have to type:

```
(initramfs) > cryptoSetup luksOpen /dev/sdc4 myVolume
(initramfs) > exit
```

Then the **Ubuntu** splashscreen appears asking again to unlock my partition.

Any ideas how to avoid the initramfs from appearing?

My grub2 entry for **Ubuntu** looks like this:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd2,gpt3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd2,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,gpt3  07baf26d-6f32-4a0d-b264-336d15177aba
else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 07baf26d-6f32-4a0d-b264-336d15177aba
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg0-root ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd /initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
```

My boot partition looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: (Windows)

Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    239616 975491071 975251456  465G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 975491072 976771071   1280000  625M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: (Fedora)

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1    2048   1230847   1228800   600M EFI System        -> /efi
/dev/nvme1n1p2 1230848   3327999   2097152     1G Linux filesystem  -> /boot
/dev/nvme1n1p3 3328000 976773119 973445120 464.2G Linux filesystem  -> /


Disk /dev/sdc: (Ubuntu)

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdc2     4096    503807    499712   244M EFI System        -> /efi
/dev/sdc3   503808   8503295   7999488   3.8G Linux filesystem  -> /boot
/dev/sdc4  8503296 976771071 968267776 461.7G Linux filesystem  -> /
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do not use LVM nor encryption. But does not Ubuntu's grub have insmod luks and cryptomount (hdX,Y) and then would not Fedora's version need that? May be easier to use a configfile entry in Fedora to load Ubuntu either to Ubuntu's UEFI boot file (which is a configfile to grub.cfg in /) or directly to grub in /boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205982/how-make-external-usb-disk-bootable-for-bios-and-uefi Not need to post link to Boot-Repair, better to post link to the summary report so can give better details, if you need those.

Comment: Currently the menu entry in grub2 is pointing to the /boot (/dev/sdc3) in the Ubuntu disk, so if I understand correctly I need to change the entry to point to /dev/sdc2 which is the EFI portion? @oldfred

Comment: Yes, but I find when booting different drives, the boot drive is hd0 and then drives seem to normally be in SATA port order. So I have boot stanzas that do not always work, particularly when plugging in flash drives or my external SSD as then drive order changes again. I often have boot entry that says hd1, but because of added drive, have to go into grub and change to hd2 to find correct drive. Or some experiment often required.