# Nvme drive is booted from a sata drive where the grub.conf points to the nvme, does the sata drive require updating

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

The computer is a Dell Precision T-7600 single boot desktop with Ubuntu 22.04 on a nmve drive mounted to a card slot.  This drive is not recognized as a bootable drive so there is sata drive also mounted on a separate card that has a full Ubuntu 22.04 installed. Os-prober added the nmve drive to its grub.conf and grub-customizer was used to move that to the top position.  So now it boots directly to the nmve drive at startup.

But lately I've wondered about whether that sata drive should be kept updated? Currently its only used as a boot source and where the rsnapshots are being written to.

Or should the drive be reduced to only a location for just the grub files and the backups.
I am not sure of the implications of ether option.

Thanks
Jim

Additionally:  When the system updates it updates the nmve drive not the sata. Currently I log into the sata drive and update it when ever there is a kernel update. Is there a way to automate this update of the sata drive?

Comment: If at grub menu, you go to grub's limited command and list drives, does it show both drives? If not then you have to have a full boot to get drivers for NVMe drive. But you should only need a /boot partition.

Comment: The grub menu that shows up at boot shows both drives.  I am just selection the nvme drive from there to boot from  Thanks oldred

Comment: If grub sees both drives, then you only need a grub install on SATA drive. If UEFI, then only the ESP with grub. Ubuntu's Ubiquity only allows install to ESP on first drive. In your case was that SATA drive? If NVMe drive is a full install with /boot folder and grub.cfg, you can edit the 3 line grub.cfg in the ESP to directly go to the grub.cfg in the NVMe install, not the SATA install. Just change UUID. [example UEFI configfile:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205982/how-make-external-usb-disk-bootable-for-bios-and-uefi)

Comment: I believe these are both grub Legasy. I asked this question because I was wrapping myself around the axle trying to see how the grub file on the sata drive would ever get updated.  But I now believe it doesn't  matter.  Thanks again.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear about what you're actually trying to ask. If you're asking if contents of SATA drives matter if NVMe is selected as boot device (and contains EFI partition), has the GRUB installed on that and the OS, too, then you can disconnect the whoole SATA drive without issues. However, if you're not sure where your data is stored, you should start by figuring that out.